Horizontal pager blocking taps right after scroll
What I want to achieve:
I'm attempting to make something relatively similar to Instagram stories. When the user taps on either side of the screen (left / right), it should navigate between the specific story's data (picture, text etc.). If the user longpresses the middle of the screen, a different function should be called, f.e to pause the story progress (timer). When the user swipes to either side, it should navigate to a previous/next story. When the user swipes vertically (top -> bottom), a different screen should be opened, displaying more story-specific information.
How I wanted to achieve this:
A HorizontalPager to switch between the stories. Using gesture detection, specifically with a custom .pointerInput / awaitEachGesture implementation, I was hoping to handle the taps & vertical swipes. The horizontal swipes would be handled by the HorizontalPager itself.
The issue which occurs:
When the pager has been used to swipe to the next entry (story), quickly tapping the sides after the drag finished and the page is settled does not seem to actually be detected by the gesture detector. Instead of the events being handled within the awaitEachGesture, it seems to be handled by the HorizontalPager instead, specifically as a DragInteraction.Start, even though it's not a dragging movement, but a simple tap.
This results in the logic for side tapping (displaying different data from the same story) not being called. If the taps are not done directly after the swipe, but after a small delay, the awaitEachGesture implementation handles the tap correctly.
Code to reproduce the issue:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        
        setContent {
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 5 })

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                pagerState.interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
                    when (interaction) {
                        is DragInteraction.Start -> log("drag interaction start")
                        is DragInteraction.Stop -> log("drag interaction stop")
                        is DragInteraction.Cancel -> log("drag interaction cancel")
                    }
                }
            }

            Scaffold {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
                ) {
                    HorizontalPager(
                        state = pagerState,
                    ) { page ->
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                    awaitEachGesture {
                                        awaitFirstDown().also { pointerInputChange ->
                                            pointerInputChange.consume()

                                            log("first down consumed")
                                        }

                                        waitForUpOrCancellation()?.also { pointerInputChange ->
                                            pointerInputChange.consume()

                                            log("up consumed")
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Page index: $page")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun log(message: String) = Log.d(TAG, message)

    private companion object {
        const val TAG = "-=-"
    }
}


Would mind rephrasing what's exactly you want it to perform and what it does? does not seem to call the .pointerInput modifier this is not a correct statement because events you get are  not from pointerInput but awaitFirstDown and waitForUpOrCancellation gestures that are related to PointerInputChange. Do you mean you can't see awaitFirstDown nor waitForUpOrCancellation after drag has started? And what does  ensure the code being called here is the gesture detector, rather than an interaction with the pager? mean?

Hey, I've edited my question with more background information! I've kept the code example the same, as this example has the same 'issue', without extra implementations which are not relevant to the problem itself.

I think my answer should solve your problem. It happens because Pager, internally LazyList, checks awaitFirstDown without considering if it's consumed then after scroll started since it's consumed you don't receive awaitFirstDown nor up gestures. By setting requireUnconsumed = false you will be able to get them no matter what

It looks promising, I'm currently doing some testing, I'll get back to you afterwards! I figured editing the question in the first place would be valuable either way, for example if other people stumbled upon this.

If it's the issue is not being able to receive awaitFirstDown nor waitForUpOrCancellation after drag starts is it happens because pager consumes awaitFirstDown or other ones and because of that you won't able to get it unless you call awaitFirstDown with requireUnconsumed = false which will let awaitFirstDown to get event and following up even if any descendant or, ancestor depending on pass, Modifier consumed it.
Also, drag modifiers call awaitFirstDown with false and PointerEventPass.Initial and thanks to that drag can receive gestures even if you consume them and before any child modifier thanks to pass, which makes consuming useless against drag gestures which prints as in your case without setting requireUnconsumed = false
 I  Is it consumed before false
 I  first down consumed
 I  drag interaction start
 I  drag interaction stop

If you set requireUnconsumed = false and tap while drag is going on it will log
 I  Is it consumed before false
 I  first down consumed
 I  drag interaction start
 I  drag interaction stop
 I  Is it consumed before true
 I  first down consumed
 I  drag interaction start
 I  up consumed
 I  drag interaction cancel

As you can see in result you can still get up PointerInputCgange? while pagerState.isScrollInProgress

Demo
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 5 })

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        pagerState.interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is DragInteraction.Start -> println("drag interaction start")
                is DragInteraction.Stop -> println("drag interaction stop")
                is DragInteraction.Cancel -> println("drag interaction cancel")
            }
        }
    }

    var color by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Color.Blue)
    }

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Idle")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        Text(text = text, color = color, fontSize = 14.sp, maxLines = 2)

        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        awaitEachGesture {
                            val down = awaitFirstDown(
                                requireUnconsumed = false
                            ).also { pointerInputChange ->

                                println("Is it consumed before ${pointerInputChange.isConsumed}")
                                pointerInputChange.consume()
                                println("first down consumed, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}")
                            }

                            text = "Down $down, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}"
                            color = Color.Red


                            val up = waitForUpOrCancellation()
                                ?.also { pointerInputChange ->
                                    pointerInputChange.consume()
                                    println("up consumed, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}")
                                }

                            text = "Up isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress},  $up"
                            color = Color.Magenta
                        }
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                Text(text = "Page index: $page")
            }
        }
    }
}

More detailed explanation about gestures you can check this answer.
And drag detection code of LazyLists which also happens to be Pager too, that checks first down
private fun Modifier.dragDirectionDetector(state: PagerState) =
    this then Modifier.pointerInput(state) {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitEachGesture {
                val downEvent =
                    awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false, pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
                var upEventOrCancellation: PointerInputChange? = null
                state.upDownDifference = Offset.Zero // Reset
                while (upEventOrCancellation == null) {
                    val event = awaitPointerEvent(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
                    if (event.changes.fastAll { it.changedToUp() }) {
                        // All pointers are up
                        upEventOrCancellation = event.changes[0]
                    }
                }

                state.upDownDifference = upEventOrCancellation.position - downEvent.position
            }
        }
    }

If you don't want waitUpOrCancel to return null when you move your finger out of bounds copy-paste source code of it and comment the line as i did.
suspend fun AwaitPointerEventScope.waitMyForUpOrCancellation(
    pass: PointerEventPass = PointerEventPass.Main
): PointerInputChange? {
    while (true) {
        val event = awaitPointerEvent(pass)
        if (event.changes.fastAll { it.changedToUp() }) {
            // All pointers are up
            return event.changes[0]
        }

        if (event.changes.fastAny {


            val consumed =    it.isConsumed

                println("Consumed: $consumed")
                consumed

//                        || it.isOutOfBounds(size, extendedTouchPadding)
            }
        ) {
            return null // Canceled
        }

//        // Check for cancel by position consumption. We can look on the Final pass of the
//        // existing pointer event because it comes after the pass we checked above.
//        val consumeCheck = awaitPointerEvent(PointerEventPass.Final)
//        if (consumeCheck.changes.fastAny { it.isConsumed }) {
//            println("Consume check consumed...")
//            return null
//        }
    }
}

On real device with this modifier that removes bound and final pass consume check outcome is with only one single pointer or using another pointer while swipe is in action is as

@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 5 })

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        pagerState.interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is DragInteraction.Start -> println("drag interaction start")
                is DragInteraction.Stop -> println("drag interaction stop")
                is DragInteraction.Cancel -> println("drag interaction cancel")
            }
        }
    }

    var color by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Color.Blue)
    }

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Idle")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        Text(text = text, color = color, fontSize = 14.sp, maxLines = 2)

        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
        ) { page ->

            val pageColor = when (page) {
                0 -> Color.Cyan
                1 -> Color.Magenta
                2 -> Color.Green
                3 -> Color.Yellow
                else -> Color.Blue
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(pageColor)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        awaitEachGesture {
                            val down = awaitFirstDown(
                                requireUnconsumed = false
                            ).also { pointerInputChange ->
                                println("Is it consumed before ${pointerInputChange.isConsumed}")
                                pointerInputChange.consume()
                                println("first down consumed, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}")
                            }

                            text = "Down, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress},  $down"
                            color = Color.Red


                            val up = waitMyForUpOrCancellation()
                                ?.also { pointerInputChange ->
                                    println("up consumed, isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}")
                                }

                            text = "Up isScrolling: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress},  $up"
                            color = Color.Magenta
                        }
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                Text(text = "Page index: $page")
            }
        }
    }
}


While setting requireUnconsumed = false does result in the first block of code being called (the awaitFirstDown), it does not detect when the user lets go of the screen (waitForUpOrCancellation). I believe this happens due to DragInteraction.Start being handled, even when the user is in fact not dragging, resulting in a cancellation.
With your example code, swiping to the next 'entry' and immediately (after the scroll finished) clicking on the sides of the screen, does not actually print the up consumed line.

In my tests tapping screen again while drag is still going on i can see up consumed in the logs i shared. waitForUpOrCancellation should be invoked with PointerInputChange? if awaitFirstDown is invoked. Are you sure it's not invoked?

Hey, I've created a screen recording and uploaded this to youtube, so you can see the steps I take (using taps and movement feedback on the device) and the logs it prints. Hopefully this helps! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHDtIdNeJp4

You can check edited code to show touching while scroll is in progress. As you can see up gesture is also invoked while scroll is in progress. I can see all up events whether when you scroll or not are received as supposed to be. You can test with the new code i posted.

Maybe it is an issue with jetpack Compose version. I'm not only able to see it on logs but screen too as you can see in gif. I use 1.7.0-rc01 for the demos

Also are touching with another index while scroll is going or releasing scroll and touching again with same finger? I'm doing it with one finger on emulator

Hey, thanks for all the quick responses! I was using the compose bom 2024.08.00 (compose v1.68), but after upgrading to 1.7.0-rc01 it still does not seem to work. The waitForUpOrCancellation method returns null, I'm assuming due to the fact that the HorizontalPager is convinced the user is dragging, thus cancelling the up event, when it's actually just a simple tap. I've taken your code, and uploaded a new video here: https://youtu.be/BrKtXWbaDwA
I'm scrolling using my finger, after which I quickly tap on the screen with the same finger (after release) on a physical device.

Returning null means you receive the event. But outside of bounds of current page. In the gif above i touch in the same page and because of it returns PointerInputChange, if it returns null it means you still receive the event but it's not up but cancel as the names suggests it either returns up or cancel. You said that you don't receive the event but you do. If you touch the same page as i do you won't get null but the point is null or not you are able to get it after finger is up. With text on screen it's easier to track.

Just apply same Modifier to a Composable without pager and touch it then lift you finger out of it and you will see that you still get event but up is null. If you lift inside bounds of Composable that Modifier is attached to you will get PointerInputChange. That how that gesture works

That's the issue, when we tap the (new) screen right after swiping to it, it will cancel the event, as the HorizontalPager thinks we are dragging, even though it's just a normal tap.
Due to the event being canceled, we are not able to handle our tap logic, which should occur only when an up has been detected (when the user lets go), and not when the user swipes (cancel).
We think it might have something to do with the slop not being configured correctly after it scrolls, as the tap (without moving) seems to always be detected as a drag start, resulting in a cancel.

Very simply put: We tap on the page, but the HorizontalPager sees it as a drag event.

I don't have an physical device at the moment. I added a version of waitUpOrCancel that doesn't check if your finger is out of bounds. Would you mind checking with it?

I also see that it also returns on final pass after checking Pager. If you remove bounds and final pass check it works on physical device too.

I've tried your new solution, with the custom version of the waitUpOrCancel, but it seems to result in the pager being a lot less reactive (swipes required to go to the previous/next entry are a lot larger). Our issue is not related to it being out of bounds, its due to the fact that the taps on the pager (right after it finishes scrolling), somehow trigger a DragInteraction.Start, even though it is not a drag...

If you stop consuming them with new gesture this probably won't be an issue. Because instead of not having the gesture you are now getting it and consuming it. In waitForUpAndCancel i didn't only remove out of bounds but removed checking if Pager consumed it in final pass which happens after drag, so bypassing it lets you get the gesture but you are consuming it while you shouldn't. There is no need to consume it. And if DragInteraction:Start is being triggered then you can add a custom logic to not invoke action if it's a tap based on if it's consumed before and some other params. In

I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding your last comment. Adding the waitMyForUpOrCancellation (straight from the post) results in the pager being almost unresponsive to swipes. While removing the consume in the block of val up = waitMyForUpOrCancellation()?.also makes the pager response again, this still results in quick taps not being detected (as the pointer id value does not increase). This still results in the same issue as before, namely that taps right after swiping are seen as a drag and not as a tap, thus not invoking the code, as the function returns null (cancel)

I tested the code with waitMyForUpOrCancellation on a real device and had no issues. I can see on screen and logs that up is called with new pointer id. And what i meant in comment above waitMyForUpOrCancellation i removed where it checks if event is consumed in final or last pass by Pager and thanks to that you should be able get up which i do btw. And since you are able to get it now consuming it might cause unwanted effect on Pager and because of that you can stop consuming it. And if drag start being invoked is not desired outcome you can apply a logic to not invoke action there

Do you have any suggestions as to what logic I can use to determine whether the drag event is an actual drag (swiping to a different story) or a tap? As for the testing, I'm not consistently getting new pointer IDs, see video here: https://youtu.be/Fa7jN8uNj5A. Within the video, you can see that the pointer ID starts at 69. the swipe updates the ID to 72, but then the tap right after does not increment the ID value...

On my device and on emulator i had no issues with the code above as in gif. It might be device specific bug as well.

I'm having the issue on both a Samsung Galaxy Fold 4 and a Samsung Galaxy S21. It's a shame, because even though the delay between scroll and being able to detect taps properly is quite small in the test use case, it's around 600ms in our actual application, which affects the user experience by quite a bit... Having to wait half a second before another action can be taken is quite a delay

I tested on Samsung A50 had no issues as you can see in gif. Instead of adding this modifier to descendants of HorizontalPager add it directly to Pager and change pass to Initial so this gesture would always get it before pager. In that case i think you would be able to get up as well in your devices too. waitMyForUpOrCancellation(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial) and you can try setting pass to initial for awaitFirstDown as well. I tried it and it works on my device too

I've got 2 recordings here, with added background colors for clarity. Physical device: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IDHa2arVjBE & emulator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuDfdWJejmM. As you can see, neither seem to properly register the tap as a pointer event, if tapped quickly after the pager switches to a different page. NOTE: These are recordings from before your last comment (about moving the modifier), we seem to have posted at around the same time.

It's very likely buggy on some devices. I posted working gif in the answer as you can which it should work as intended with correct pointer ids. You should work with the latest suggestions if you have no specific requirement to assign Modifier to Boxes inside HorizontalPager. By assigning Modifier to pager with Initial pass you can call down and up before it propagates to pager

It might be a bit buggy on some devices, however, with moving the modifier to the HorizontalPager using pass = PointerEventPass.Initial it seems to always increment the ID when quickly tapping after the paging. The only issue is that the up consumed now never seems to be called again, not with the custom waitMyForUpOrCancellation nor the standard waitForUpOrCancellation. This results in the app not being able to detect when the user finished their gesture  (in this case), thus never being able to execute the logic for handling taps

You can remove consume forwaitMyForUpOrCancellation but The only issue is that the up consumed now never seems to be called again doesn't make no sense. Because events and consumes only apply to current one. Consuming one event doesn't make next one not eligible to invoked. and wait up is nothing other than checking awaitPointerEvent(pass) and should work when pass is Initial with any gesture modifier following current one

I don't experience anything you post even in emulator videos. Emulator should work same for everyone while for you it doesn't. It might be due to some developer options you might have enabled. As you can see on gif it works exactly it's supposed to be on real Samsung device as well. At this point you should try testing another device or with different developer options

Ah apologies, what I meant with The only issue is that the up consumed now never seems to be called again is that the log is never called anymore, not even with a simple tap, due to the event always being marked as cancelled, thus returning null within the methods, which means it does not execute the also {} block for the up event. By removing the consume within the down.also it seems like the up block is called with normal taps, but it's still not being called if the user quickly taps after scrolling...

Testing on my personal device, which does not have developer options enabled in the first place, still had the same results. I'm honestly unsure as to where it goes wrong. Quickly tapping after paging seems to always be handled as a drag start, which results in the event being cancelled and thus not executing the block within the val up = waitMyForUpOrCancellation()?.also {, neither with or without a defined pass.

You should put a log inside waitForUpOrCancellation to see why it gets cancelled then. It should always go into that block before pager receives gesture because initial pass

https://youtu.be/oyftuQINQrI Here's a video which shows my logs and actions. As you can see in the video, normal tapping ends up executing the code within the up block. When I swipe and quickly tap, however, you can see that the pagerState starts a DragInteraction.Start, and that up == null. However, I am not dragging, just a simple tap. When re-adding the pass = PointerEventPass.Initial to the waitMyForUpOrCancellation, the up block will always be called, even when the user is dragging and it shouldn't be called...

Also as i see from your code you are not testing the code exactly i posted. It might be due to something else. Why don't you first test the code as i posted it. It has preview annotation and you can simply copy paste and test it you know to be sure that it might be due to Scaffold or another Composable you know

Just test the code without any activity or Scaffold to be sure that it works as i said on emulator as well. Then you can add other Composables to pinpoint where this issue comes from.

Straight up copy-pasting your latest code examples results in the behaviour I described. The pager itself is less response than the 'default, requiring a lot more movement before it does something. When just dragging, the up.also block is always executed, even when dragging.

I made a screen recording here, which straight up copy-pasted the code you had in your answer. In the recording I show all the code which is being used (there's no extra components or anything added). As you can see, without any changes, the pager barely registers swipes, and always calls the up event, even when the user is dragging and it should not be called. EDIT: Forgot to add the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDMVLBc3hh4
